# Illustrator Action - resizing a rectangle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, actions

Many, many times a day I have to add .5 to the width and length of a clipping mask to add bleed for printing. I really want to make this a key stroke or at least a action button. so I can click on the mask then the button.

The issue is when I record the action it doesn't record +.5 it records "Scale width to 5555 pt"

Is there a way to get around this or is this a script?

Comment: Yes but its not possible to bind the script to a shurtcut/button easily without needing to record it again every session.

Answer (score 1):

Script could look like this.

```
#target illustrator

var sel  = activeDocument.selection;
var RU = activeDocument.rulerUnits;
activeDocument.rulerUnits = RulerUnits.Points;

for(var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++){
    if(sel[i].typename == "PathItem"){
        sel[i].width+=0.5;
    }
}
activeDocument.rulerUnits = RU;
```

Making this a shortcut and a button that will be easily accessible from session to session, is another ballgame... It can be done but its quite convoluted.

Comment: @JasonDennis As joojaa implies, illustrator doesn't quite support setting a a hotkey to launch a script, but there are ways to do it. In mac setting a script hotkey is easy ( Automator ). In windows, the only way I know is with Auto Hotkey, but I only know how to make it a global hotkey that can be triggered from any application. Not that I use illustrator in windows much or at all. Joojaa, you know a better way in windows by any chance?

Comment: @Joonas you can reload your actions after load is fully done. It can be automatically done with a bit of c code. You can make tool windows so button is possible. You can call a batch script on target app hook.

Comment: @Jason Maybe you already figured it out, but [here's a video showing how to do set a hotkey for a script with automator](https://youtu.be/M5EWASSk9MI). **–––** I like to use [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/)  for this type of stuff. Mostly because compared to automator, you get to have/set the hotkey in the same place where the macro lives. So it's easier to manage. [So here's video on how you can do it with Alfred](https://youtu.be/_ehFIR3nYz4).