# Shortcut to change the size of a rectangle in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Suppose I have a rectangle, and would like to resize both the width and the height by increasing 4mm,
Any idea if I could accomplish that through a shortcut / action / JS script?
I tried to record that directly with an action, yet that does not allow a an increment to the size.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62439/illustrator-action-resizing-a-rectangle/62442#62442

Comment: In addition to script you can use offset instead for boxes its all same but it is a recordable action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method:-

1. Select the rectangles you want to resize then go to **OBJECT(menu)>PATH>Offset path**
2. You can now enter the size you want to increase or decrease (by entering offset value). **DONE**!!

as you want to increase same height and width, this method just work perfect for you

here's the demonstration
[image]

Comment: You are probably being downvoted because this does not answer the question. What if OP wants to resize 100 shapes this way. It isnt a shortcut.

Comment: I have made some changes to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried transform again shortcut? (Control/Command + D)

You perform a transform setting on one object then you select another object and do Cmd+D. It will transform the new object with the same setting.